# Is there free equivalent of Resharper's "Move to Resource" functionality in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, resources, resharper

Is there free equivalent of Resharper's ["Move to Resource"](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Resources__Refactorings__Move_to_Resource.html) functionality in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [resource refactoring tool](http://resourcerefactoring.codeplex.com/) is a great addon for that

Answer (score 0):

I've found myself another solution: [CodeRush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/)

[image]